# How to filter ReportViewer by DateTime of the table

Tags: c#, .net, mysql

I am using Visual Studio 2010, C# and MySQL.

I created a DataSet and filled it with my table, this table shows **all dates**, but I'd like ReportViewer to show only the dates of current day, like DateTime.Now.

I'm trying

```
=FormatDateTime(now,DateTime.ToLongDateString) + " ás " + Format(now,"HH:mm")
```

How can I do this ?

Comment: Why don't you filter data before you fill it to data table? With that you can prevent unwanted data coming from server to client.

Comment: I dont get it... I Fill my datatable with dayly dates. And on the dataset I used a wizard guide, should I use Select command ? If so, How Would I fill the report with this created dataset? Like Dataset ds = new Dataset();